# iOS displaying map in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I want to uses this map: http://agence.orange.fr/fr/ile-de-france/paris in my application, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple google map. They have put their custom pins on the map at particular location. On pin click they are zooming the map to show the detailed map. You can easily do it if you have latitude-longitude of those points on which they have dropped a custom pin.

Use iOS SDK for Google map and you can start for it.

Comment: So as I understand I have to initialise  latitude-longitude of those points by myself, or I can get them directly from that site?

Comment: You cant get it from site. You need to call some backend service which supplies those points to the web site.

Comment: In this case can't I just display directly only that map from the page, so the other content will not be shown?

Comment: You may open that web page in your webview...

Comment: Yeah but it means that all the other stuff at web will be also shown, can I hide it somehow?

Comment: Its much more complex than to fetch data from backend..